# Show that $K$ is at most countable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a subset of real number. Define a set $K:=\{a\in A: \exists \varepsilon_a>0, (a-\varepsilon_a, a)\cap A=\emptyset\}$. Show that $K$ is at most countable.

---

My idea is to consider the function
$$
\phi: K\to \mathbb{Q}
$$
by $\phi(a)=(a-\varepsilon_a, a)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ for some $\varepsilon_a>0$.

It is enough to show that $\phi$ is injective. For any $a\neq b\in K$, I am stuck on how to show that $\phi(a)\neq \phi(b)$...

It seems that $I_a:=(a-\varepsilon_a, a)$ is either $I_a=I_b$ or $I_a\cap I_b=\emptyset$. (If $I_a\cap I_b\neq \emptyset$, then take $x\in I_a\cap I_b$. It contradicts with the fact that $I_a\cap A=I_y\cap A=\emptyset$?...)

Comment: In order to assert that $I_a=I_b$ or $I_a\cap I_b=\emptyset$ you have to take $\epsilon_a$ to be the supremum of all $\epsilon >0$ such that $(a-\epsilon, a)\cap A=\emptyset$. And you have to fill in the details of this important step.

Comment: Also, the function $\phi$ is not well defined.

Comment: For all $a,b\in K$: If $b<a$ then $b\notin (a-\epsilon_a,a)$. If $a<b$ then $a\notin(b-\epsilon_b,b)$.

Comment: Correct @H.YDuan. Those intervals cannot overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K_\delta:=\{a\in A\mid(a-\delta, a)\cap A=\emptyset\}$.
Now for $\delta >0$ we have$$K_\delta=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K_\delta\cap[-n,n]$$
so $K_\delta$ is countable (since it is a countable union of the finite sets $K_\delta\cap[-n,n]$).
Now $$K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N^*}}K_{\frac{1}{n}}$$
is clearly countable.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151007/discussion-on-answer-by-eulersgroupie-show-that-k-is-at-most-countable); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The intervals $(a-\epsilon_a,a)$, $(b-\epsilon_b,b)$ cannot overlap whenever $a,b\in K$ are distinct. Consequently, for all positive integers $n$, there can only be at most countably infinitely many numbers $a\in K$ such that it is possible to choose $\epsilon_a>1/n$.

Comment: I might call this a hint rather than an answer.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was just created (because I just replied to a comment here). Nothing wrong then.

Comment: Ok. No harm done!